# Specifying the default WS Trust credentials in web.config

Tags: wcf, wif, claims-based-identity, ws-trust

I have a custom STS implemented with WIF. My WS-Trust services are using these configurations:

```
<behavior name="WSTrustServiceBehaviour">
    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />

    <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
            <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust"
                            revocationMode="NoCheck"
                            trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine"/>
        </clientCertificate>

        <serviceCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            storeName="TrustedPeople"
                            x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"
                            findValue="5BF081CCC2E20094D0648F0A3F3C6A598155D606"/>
    </serviceCredentials>
</behavior>

<ws2007HttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSTrustHttpBinding">
        <security>
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"
                     negotiateServiceCredential="false" 
                     establishSecurityContext="false"/>
        </security>
    </binding>
</ws2007HttpBinding>

<service name="System.ServiceModel.Security.WSTrustServiceContract"
         behaviorConfiguration="WSTrustServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint name="WSTrust13HttpEndpoint"
              address="http/v13"
              binding="ws2007HttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="WSTrustHttpBinding"
              contract="System.ServiceModel.Security.IWSTrust13AsyncContract"/>
    <endpoint name="WSTrustFeb05HttpEndpoint"
              address="http/feb05"
              binding="ws2007HttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="WSTrustHttpBinding"
              contract="System.ServiceModel.Security.IWSTrustFeb2005AsyncContract" />
    <endpoint name="WSTrustMexHttpEndpoint"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration=""
              address="http/mex"
              contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
        <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://services.example.com" />
        </baseAddresses>
    </host>
</service>
```

Now I have one Web application that needs to call a WCF service. Both the Web application and the WCF Service are both Relying Parties of my custom STS. In my Web application's web.config, I have the following:

```
<ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyWCFServiceWS2007FederationHttpBinding"
             useDefaultWebProxy="false"
             messageEncoding="Mtom">
        <security mode="Message">
            <message>
                <issuer address="http://sts.example.com/WSTrust.svc/http/feb05"
                        binding="ws2007HttpBinding"
                        bindingConfiguration="WSTrustHttpBinding"/>
                <issuerMetadata address="http://sts.example.com/Bus/WSTrust.svc/http/mex"/>
            </message>
        </security>
    </binding>
</ws2007FederationHttpBinding>

<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyWCFServiceWS2007HttpEndpointBehavior">
        <clientCredentials supportInteractive="false"
                           useIdentityConfiguration="true">
            <serviceCertificate>
                <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust"
                                revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
            </serviceCertificate>
        </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>

<client>
    <endpoint name="MyWCFServiceWS2007FederationHttpEndpoint"
              address="http://services.example.com/MyWCFService.svc/..."
              binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="MyWCFServiceWS2007FederationHttpBinding"
              contract="..."
              behaviorConfiguration="IdentityWS2007HttpEndpointBehavior"/>
</client>
```

Now the problem is that when I try to invoke My WCF Service using the client endpoint, WCF will first contact the STS WS-Trust endpoint to get a token.

But the WS-Trust Service is expecting the client to present a certificate to authenticate himself. How can I specify these credentials in the web.config?

I think in code I would do something like:

```
var trustChannelFactory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(..., ...);

trustChannelFactory.TrustVersion = System.ServiceModel.Security.TrustVersion.WSTrust13;

trustChannelFactory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;

// Set the credentials here:
trustChannelFactory.Credentials  ...
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.